# Python: Is it a good practice to rely on import to execute code?

Tags: python, import, architecture

In Python, is it a good practice to rely on import to execute code, like in the example below?

The code in `mod.py` is supposed to load some config, and needs to be executed once only. It can use more complex logic, but its purpose is to establish values of some parameters, later used as configuration by `main.py`.

```
# --- mod.py ---
param1 = 'abc'
param2 = 'def'
# ...


# --- main.py ---
import mod

p1 = mod.param1
p2 = mod.param2
# (then calls functions from other components, which use p1, p2, ... as arguments)
```

Comment: FWIW, I think it's bad practice. Controlling what gets executed + when becomes a nightmare

Comment: A module should run whatever code is needed to initialize itself to become ready to use. What is means depends on the specification of the module. Another rule (and more important IMO) is that the importing should have no side-effects. In my understanding, no modification of system settings, no I/O, no long CPU computation, no network access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Defining* things in an additional module is perfectly fine - variables, classes, functions etc.

When the module is imported, as long as you don't use `from ... import *` your namespace does not get cluttered and you can extract a standalone and/or repeated fragments to have cleaner code.

It's pretty much an intended use for modules.

What is not so good, is having code with *side-effects* that gets executed on import. This here gives a nice example why it's not a good idea: 
[Say “no” to import side‐effects in Python](https://chrismorgan.info/blog/say-no-to-import-side-effects-in-python/)

Answer (score 3):

> code in `mod.py` is supposed to load some config, and needs to be
> executed once only.

Using [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) statement leads to

1. find a module, loading and initializing it if necessary
2. define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where the `import` statement occurs.

therefore even numerous usage of `import mod` will lead to execution of code in it just once, consider following toy example, let `mod.py` content be

```
print("I am mod.py")
```

and `main.py` content be

```
import mod
import mod
import mod
```

then output of `python main.py` will be

```
I am mod.py
```

Comment: Given the "will-be-executed-once" property of imported code, it seems that a reasonable *demand* is the system being "agnostic" to which import triggered the execution. NON-EXAMPLE: `if X in globals(): X = 8` for the imported code, and 2 different import places, one with `X=7 ... import` and the other with `Y=7 ... import` ...

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to import only what's necessary and if possible, write the code in a function and use:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    call_function()
```

at the end of the code, so that when you go back and change your code (add new variables/manipulate older variables), they won't create a problem.

It's always a good practice to callthe function yourself after that, instead of relying on the import to run it. In your other file, you can import call_function() and then run it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** for loading configs, I would save configs in a YAML file then read it by PyYAML (`import yaml`). I would write a loader in some util.py and call the loader in main.py. Also, according to the Zen of Python:

> Explicit is better than implicit
> Flat is better than nested.

---

**e.g. Facebook AI Research**'s Detectron2 use `detectron2/tools/train_net.py` to train a neural network with parameters loaded from a config file. Like this:

```bash
$ ./tools/train_net.py --num-gpus 8 \
  --config-file ./configs/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_1x.yaml
```

Here the the [`main()`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/cbbc1ce26473cb2a5cc8f58e8ada9ae14cb41052/tools/train_net.py#L131) in train_net.py calls `setup()` first which runs `get_cfg()` imported from `detectron2.config`:

```py
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
```

BTW a yaml config file looks like:

```yaml
_BASE_: "../Base-RCNN-FPN.yaml"
MODEL:
  # WEIGHTS: "detectron2://ImageNetPretrained/MSRA/R-50.pkl"
  # For better, more stable performance initialize from COCO
  WEIGHTS: "detectron2://COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl"
  MASK_ON: True
  ROI_HEADS:
    NUM_CLASSES: 8
  ...
  ...
  IMS_PER_BATCH: 8
TEST:
  EVAL_PERIOD: 8000
```

[The documentation of PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

Comment: What if I have a bunch of YMLs that I want to load and then bundle together into a single "parameters" object? And I don't want to do it in the `main.py`.

Comment: @wojciech Loading a YAML file is turning it into a dictionary. If you have a bunch of them, each with different keys, then you may simply merge the dictionaries. I would imagine you don't have conflict across the files anyway because you have a single parameter object in mind.

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing inside mod.py. My question was whether it is good design to transfer the results of this operation from mod.py to main.py by importing mod.py (and hence all the names in it), as opposed to e.g. defining a function inside mod.py (and importing + executing it in main.py).

Comment: @wojciech ahh I see haha, usually what people do is to write a configuration file loader in some util.py and explicitly call it in the main Python scripts and save this dictionary into a variable in the main script to pass it around functions. There is one colleague of mine who hated config files, but he still calls a function that reads cmd line args in main. Sorry if I'm not being helpful here but I am not qualified to talk about the best practice here lol. I

Comment: @wojciech I modified the answer and hope the example is clear.